# SharePoint Designer Workflow extracting values from Multiline Rich Text field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, jquery-ui

I am trying to read a multiline rich text field from a different list in SharePoint Designer Workflow.

The rich text field has multiple lines.
My workflow errors out give HTTP500 error all the time when I try to read the content from the field.

I don't have append changes settings either.

Comment: What did you mean by "read a multiline rich text field from a different list "? Could you share how you design your workflow? and

Comment: Please provide your details, so that we can reproduce this issue to help you better.